# Работа метода type_keys в разных раскладках (Eng/Rus)

Tags: pywinauto

Я работаю с SAPGUI через pywinauto.
При выполнении **`window.type_keys('^N')`** в англ.раскладке - SAPGUI создает новое окно.

При выполнении **`window.type_keys('^N')`** в русской раскладке, SAPGUI игнорирует команду.
Если руками нажать **`Ctrl+N`** в русской раскладке - SAPGUI создает новое окно.

Для работы с SAPGUI мне необходимо:

- имитировать нажатие кнопок (англ)
- вводить текст в элементы (рус/англ)

**Вопрос**: *Есть ли возможность передавать последовательности нажатия кнопок без необходимости программно менять раскладку?*

Comment: Для ввода текста менять раскладку не обязательно. `.type_keys()` воспринимает всё как Unicode. На всякий случай уточните версию и битность питона. Насчёт комбинаций клавиш проверю попозже.

Comment: Есть одно предположение... если SAPGUI сам учитывает раскладку, то можно попробовать “^Т” (русскую Т, которая на клавиатуре соответствует N). Если отреагирует, то это, по идее, особенность самого SAPGUI.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ Василий. Я смотрел ваши исходники и в курсе что вы передаете все как Unicode, тут как бы претензий к вам нет. Была надежда что кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой. По ней как раз уточню: в рус. раскладке SAPGUI отображает все символы(рус/анг) в поля ввода корректно, в англ. раскладке все русские символы заменяет вопросительными знаками.Непонятно почему это для hot-key не работает. И да “^Т” работает.

Comment: python 3.6.0(32bit) и 3.7.2(64bit) под Win10, pywinauto 0.6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну на самом деле в отношении SAPGUI ответ будет: **Нет, нельзя**.
Подытожу:
1) Для вставки русских символов обязательно нужно переключить
    раскладку на русскую.
2) При включенной русской раскладке комбинации
    клавиш с латинскими буквами не работают корректно. Нужно в
    комбинациях заменить латинские буквы на соответствующие русские.
    *Например: заменить **^N** на **^Т***
Для тех кто не знает как переключать раскладку программно привожу пример функции:

```
def setCyrillicLayout():
    window_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    result = win32api.SendMessage(window_handle, 0x0050, 0, 0x04190419)
    return(result)
```

Comment: Кстати, спасибо за идею с раскладкой. Завёл [фича реквест](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/704). И да, свой собственный ответ тут тоже можно акцептить.

Answer (score 0):

### Переключение раскладки клавиатуры в PYTHON реально работает. Спасибо.
Это единственный форум, где рабочий вариант представлен.

```
import win32api
import win32gui


def setCyrillicLayout():
    window_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    result = win32api.SendMessage(window_handle, 0x0050, 0, 0x04190419)
    return(result)

def setEngLayout():
    window_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    result = win32api.SendMessage(window_handle, 0x0050, 0, 0x04090409)
    return(result)


#Переключить на русскую
#setCyrillicLayout()

#Переключить на англ
setEngLayout()
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).